# Change company on an EU blue card visa

Tags: visa, germany, eu, blue-card

I have a situation and I would appreciate your help.

I had an offer from a startup company in Germany and after they mailed me the signed contract, I went to the German embassy and applied for a blue card visa and got it with the company's name printed on it.

After that I received another opportunity, which is far better than the previous one. Now I want join the new company. So what will be the process to change the company on the visa? Do I need that?

Is there any paperwork that should be done in my current case?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/12356/changing-jobs-after-6-months-as-a-blue-card-holder

Comment: @mkennedy not all answers in that question may be correct

Comment: if you have signed that contract, then it is also binding on you.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot switch your employer on a Blue Card at this stage without petitioning the authorities. You will need to apply for a new Blue Card with the new employer.

Blue Cards are tied to the employer for the first two years, unless changed by petition.

Answer (score 0):

At [this FAQ page](http://www.bamf.de/EN/Infothek/FragenAntworten/BlaueKarteEU/blaue-karte-eu-node.html) of German Federal Office for Migration website, it is stated that you can apply for an approval for change in your employment with no extra conditions than your initial application.

About your specific situation, where you had not even started working with your employer who sponsored you for your EU blue card; it is also stated in the last sentence that you can still apply if your issued Blue Card is terminated '**prematurely**'.

> **Question**: From what point in time may I change employers?
>
> > **Answer**: Any change of job during the first two years of employment requires the approval of the immigration authority (section 19a subs. 4 of the German Residence Act). Approval is subject to the same preconditions as initial issuance. If the minimum gross salary threshold has been raised during the intervening period, compliance with the new threshold must be proven. Holders of an EU Blue Card are obliged to inform the competent immigration authority if the employment for which the EU Blue Card was issued is terminated prematurely

**By the way**, as someone in same situation at the moment, I am extremely curious how you went through the process, from getting an appointment to approval. I would appreciate if you can give some details about authorities' opinions of this premature change, possibly with a comment or edit.