# Work permit update in Berlin

Tags: germany, blue-card

I came to Berlin from India on May 2019 to work as a software engineer in a startup in Berlin.

I received my Blue Card on 30-Sep-2019 and it is valid for 4 years. I also received separate work permit which mentions my present company name.

I was told by the ausländerbehörde that in case of job change I should update them and they will update my work permit with the new company name.

I have a new job offer now. I have mailed the ausländerbehörde more than 2 weeks ago with my blue card details and the new employment contract. I haven't heard from them.

In there website there is no option to book an appointment for 'Change of Employer'. So i am not able to book any appointment. I any case my joining in the new company will be before I can get any appointments.

What should I do ? Can I join the new company with the old work permit and later update it ? Or should the new company try to get the work permit for me?

I am completely lost.

Comment: The last two weeks include the Christmas holidays, New Year's Eve, and the New Year. Something around three working days, considering that most people get at least half days off on the 24th and little work gets done on the remaining time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing jobs after 6 months as a Blue Card holder](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/12356/changing-jobs-after-6-months-as-a-blue-card-holder)

Comment: Just want to ask how did you solved this issue? I am in same situation. I have applied via email by attaching all the required documents but no response yet.

Answer (score 1):

I assume there is an option to **change** your residence permit

- if comments are allowed add **Change of employer** and the date it should take effect

Do not change your employer until this process has been completed.

---

> **Employment - Change of employer**
>   Do you have a residence permit for the purpose of employment or an EU Blue Card?
>   Does your work permit specify a particular company?
>   Do you want to change company?
>
> > Then please apply to have your residence permit for the purpose of employment or EU Blue Card **amended** (**geändert**).

Foreigners Office (Ausländerbehörde) Berlin,

- location Keplerstr.

Keplerstraße 2
10589 Berlin

---

**Sources**:

- [Employment - Change of employer - Services - Dienstleistungen - Service Berlin - Berlin.de](https://service.berlin.de/dienstleistung/326856/en/)

  - [Employment - Change of employer am Standort Foreigners Office (Ausländerbehörde) Berlin, location Keplerstr. - Dienstleistungen - Service Berlin - Berlin.de](https://service.berlin.de/dienstleistung/326856/standort/327437/en/)