# Germany Blue Card - change of company

Tags: germany, blue-card

I have a German Blue Card and want to change my employer. According to the rule for Blue Card holders:

> For the first two years of employment, approval from the Foreigners’ Registration Office must be obtained before any change of job.

My current job contract started on 01.04.2018. Am I allowed to change my employer from 01.04.2020 without approval? Can I just sign a contract that starts on 01.04.2020? I have a Blue Card visa in my passport and also as a card with different dates; are they linked?

I cannot ask the authorities as they are closed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing jobs after 6 months as a Blue Card holder](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/12356/changing-jobs-after-6-months-as-a-blue-card-holder). The authorities are not closed, they just do not accept visitors. You can call them or send email.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, after a 2 year employment (without a time limit), you can change your employer without prior approval.

---

> Note: Your residence permit for the purpose of employment/your EU Blue Card does not have to be amended, if you
>
> - have already worked for at least two years with a residence permit for the purpose of employment **or**
> - you have resided continuously in Germany for at least three years with a residence permit (except for study)
>
> **and**
>   in addition, **no time limit is fixed by law for your type of employment** (such as, for example, in the case of speciality chefs or within the framework of an exchange of personnel of an internationally operating company).
>
> You can then move to another skilled employment without prior approval. The Foreigners Registration Office will provide you with written confirmation of this on request.

---

**Sources**:

- [Employment - Change of employer am Standort Berlin Immigration Office, Friedrich-Krause-Ufer - Dienstleistungen - Service Berlin - Berlin.de](https://service.berlin.de/dienstleistung/326856/standort/121885/en/)