# Do you need "visa sponsorship" to change jobs once you have a blue card?

Tags: germany, blue-card, work-permit

Once you a get a blue card in Germany, if you want to change jobs, you have to get a new job contract and apply at the immigration office for the job change if it has been less than 2 years since you got the blue card.

But in the eyes of the next employer, are you any different from an EU citizen in that they have to do some extra sponsorship or paperwork just for you?

The reason I am asking is, many companies refuse to hire people from outside the EU because they don't want to do visa sponsorship. But does this situation change once you have a blue card and are already in Germany?

Comment: Once you have a blue card and already are in Germany, you don't need any sponsorship anymore.

Comment: @quantum So the amount of effort a new employer has to put into hiring a blue card holder is the same as a EU citizen?

Comment: Yes, why would it be different? It is not. But: you might need to go through extra trouble since you will need permission to get that new job (see https://service.berlin.de/dienstleistung/326856/standort/121885/en/) and also (https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/12356/changing-jobs-after-6-months-as-a-blue-card-holder?rq=1)

Comment: @quantum the reason I thought it would be different is because it is in other countries like the US and UK. In both these places companies have to sponsor the employee's application during a job change so many tend to prefer to not hire non-citizens. The German policy seems more accommodating since it puts the extra burden on only the employee. Thanks for the answer.